# Java Combo Boxes + Image Icons

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to build a really basic program that will alternate between two pictures depending on which item from a dropdown box is selected. This is the code I'm trying to run, but I keep getting an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:181)
at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:10)
at Apples.main(Apples.java:7)
```

The images are in the src file.

Does anyone know what I  am doing wrong??
Thanks,
Ravin

[image: this screenshot demonstrates that the images are in the src file]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame{

private JComboBox box;
private JLabel picture;
private static String [] filename = {"Ravinsface.png", "Wojs face.png"};
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0])), new      ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[1]))};

public Gui(){
super("The Title");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
box = new JComboBox(filename);
box.addItemListener(
new ItemListener(){
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED);
    picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);

}
 }

 );
add(box);
picture = new JLabel(pics[1]);
add(picture);


}

}
```

Comment: While I'm a big fan of screenshots - in this case, copy/pasting the exception stacktrace would have provided every bit of information in the image (1,241px × 1,042px & over 150Kb), & taken a **lot** less bytes to do so.

Comment: please follows tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(String)

/e1 I put an explanation of the different getResource(String) methods on the other answer.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner - can you explain what that getClassLoader is doing?

Comment: ClassLoaders are responsible for loading Classes. That is, given the name of a .class file, it should create a Class for it. Every Class is loaded by a ClassLoader, and every Class contains a reference to the ClassLoader that loaded it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one (or more) of the arguments you are passing into your ImageIcon constructor are null.  This is because the resource is not being found here:

```
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0])), new      ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[1]))};
```

Why aren't you just using

```
new ImageIcon(String filename)
```

?  I'm not 100% sure how getResource works, never having used it.

Comment: Class.getResource(String) looks inside the package for the resource.
ClassLoader.getResource(String) looks inside the source folder for the resource.
new ImageIcon(String) looks outside the source folder for the resouce.

Answer (score 0):

do this:
you must put your .png

beside your .class files
(in project_name/bin)

then your files path can recognize

then it will works 
remember you are using class loader so if you put images beside .class files it will be correct